Acknowledgment numbers in Wireshark do not match sequence numbers
Recently, I conducted an experiment involving uploading a file to a server. I noticed that the acknowledgment numbers I received did not align with the sequence numbers. Please refer to the attached screenshot.
Specifically,
Sequence numbers I sent: 1-2897-5793 ...
Acknowledgment numbers I received: 1-2897-4345-5793 ...
I'm wondering why I see 4345 in the acknowledgments. I initially suspected it might be due to the Quick Acknowledgment scheme, but I remain unsure. Additionally, since the Maximum Segment Size (MSS) is 1460 Bytes, why do we observe larger segments (e.g., sequence number 2897)?


The MSS=1460 and Len=2896 details reveal that large send offloading (LSO) seems to be used on the NIC.
Wireshark captures on the API level, with offloading hiding certain details. The actual segments/packets on the wire may be other than you see here. Disable offloading if you want to avoid that.

Hence sequence numbers and acknowledgment numbers do not add up with the same reason. Right?

They do add up eventually, but you may see 'intermediate' ACKs where there was no apparent segment boundary, just as you described.
